# How to wait until a service finishes opening a window before processing it

Tags: c#, wpf

I have code that opens a window using a service in my WPF C# application. I want to create a print-screen image file of that window once it is opened. The problem is that my code is creating an image file that has a print-screen of the area BEFORE the window is actually opened. I tried to create a delegate on the ViewOpened event, so that it waits until the window is actually opened before I generate the print screen. But I still get an image of the area BEFORE the window opens. How can I fix this?

Here is my code:

```
    private void M_printScreenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var allViews = SystemConfigurationComponent.GetAllViews();
        foreach (var view in allViews)
        {
            // TODO: Add condition to select which views to process. Maybe add a boolean field to View table.
            if (string.Equals(view.Uri, @"gtcs\gcs\mmc_userpreferences", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                ViewsIntegrationService.OpenMimic(view.Uri, "", "", 2, ThisMimic.Context, null);

                ViewsIntegrationService.ViewOpened += delegate
                {
                    using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(view.DefaultWidth, view.DefaultHeight))
                    {
                        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
                        {
                            g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(view.DefaultLeft, view.DefaultTop), Point.Empty,
                                new Size() {Width = view.DefaultWidth, Height = view.DefaultHeight});
                        }
                        bitmap.Save(@"C:\\temp\\GTCS_PrintScreens\\test.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        //bitmap.Save(view.WindowTitle.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Replace("'", string.Empty) + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    }

                    //ViewsIntegrationService.CloseView(new AlstomGuiMimicImpl(m_mimicsManager, ThisMimic));
                };
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've done this in MVVM style wpf applications, I would have the window you are opening create the screenshot and message/send it back to the caller, rather than the caller trying to create the screenshot and running into a race condition (which you are).   The window opening knows when it is ready, the caller can only guess.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are first opening the view then adding the event handler after it is opened.

Try:

```
ViewsIntegrationService.ViewOpened += delegate ...
```

Then

```
ViewsIntegrationService.OpenMimic(...
```

Additionally, the `Loaded` event is probably a better event to use for the purpose of taking a screen shot.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the image file contains the background. It seems to be always taking a snapshot before the window is actually opened.

Comment: Then perhaps you should wire up to a different event such as loaded